# Use of uninitialized value $no_issue[0] in join or string at db_connect.pl line 146

Tags: perl

I am trying to read some data from array and checking the 2 column, if it satisfy my condition I need to load entire row into another array, while doing that am getting error like

> *Use of uninitialized value $no_issue[0] in join or string at
>   db_connect.pl line 146.*

I have given my code below:

```
while (my @row = $processed_sql->fetchrow_array)
        {
            #print "sq_no: $row[0] hie_key:$row[1] today: $row[2] table_name: $row[3] batch_id: $row[4] table_count: $row[5] pre_count: $row[6]\n";
        ############################################################
        my $table_name = $row[3];
        my $batch_id = $row[4];
        my $table_count = $row[5];
        my $pre_count=$row[6];
        our @no_issue;
        #my $nvalue;

        #print "$table_name,$table_count\n";

    if($table_count >= $pre_count)

    {

        push (@no_issue,$_);

        **print "value is greater @no_issue \n";**
    }
    else
    {
        print "jkdlkjfa\n";
    }

    }
```

Comment: Please indent your whole code and I think this is a warning rather than error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
push (@no_issue, $_);

print "value is greater @no_issue \n";
```

You are pushing `$_` onto the array `@no_issue` but there is no preceding code that sets `$_` so you are pushing `undef` and then trying to print it, giving rise to a *Use of uninitialized value* error

I can't tell what values you want in that array, but presumably it's one of the elements of `@row`?